# View is not adjusting itself after hiding Tabbar

Tags: iphone

I have a UITabbar having 5 tabs like this

[image]

Now I want to hide the UITabbar when taps on the Feed Tab. I want to show the full screen there. I am able to hide the tabbar but the UIView of Feed screen is not adjusting itself and I can see the white space at the place of UITabBar. I set the frame of view after hiding the UITabbar but it is also not working. How can I get the object of UITabbarController in the UIViewController classes which are added on the UITabbar so that I can call the delegate methods of UITabbarController. For instance, how can I have the object of UITabbarController in Feed Class.Please Help! If I am not clear please let me know.
Thanks-

Comment: Did you try to call `[myView setNeedsDisplay];` after hiding the tab bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` inside of `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;` of the Feed class implementation like so:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        //more of your initialization code...
    }
    return self;
}
```

It should be in `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;` and not `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;` as your view is loaded from the .xib file by the application.

Comment: Thanks Ariel! It worked for me. Since three days I am struggling for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Ariel answer, you need to set "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed" property to YES,when you are loading it from the nib.
As " initWithCoder"-Method is called if you are loading from the nib, you need to set that property there only. 
Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Since, Ariel had answered before you so I should accept his answer but I have up voted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set self.navigationController.view.frame size when you hide the tabbar.
You can get the fullscreen size with [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].